# Entity Framework Core PostgreSQL parse query string for full text search same way as to_tsvector

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, full-text-search

I need to configure full text search by column with text.

I configure generated field for full text search, and parse text value as `to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(my_text_field, ''))`

Then I get user input string (example `Apple street 1/3 13-74`) and want to parse it to ts_query same way as to_tsvector parse `my_text_field`, to avoid different parsing, for example parse `1/3` as single value and `13-74` as `13` and `-74`. Expected transformation of user input is `Apple street 1/3` -> `Apple & street $ 1/3 & 13 & -74`.

I try to do

```cs
IQueryable<MyType> source;
source = source.Where(x =>
    x.SearchField.Matches(
         EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("simple", EF.Functions.ToTsVector("simple", userInput
                                .Select(x => x.Text)
                                .Aggregate("", (seq, item) => $"{seq} & {item}")))));
```

But it doesn't work.

I try to do it with raw sql, and it look like

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE search @@ (SELECT to_tsquery(query_string) FROM
(SELECT array_to_string(query_arr, '&') as query_string
FROM
    (SELECT array_agg(lexemes) as query_arr
    FROM
        (SELECT
            vector.lexeme as lexemes
        FROM
            unnest(to_tsvector('simple', 'SOME USER INPUT'))
                as vector)
            as query_arr)
        as result) as rqs);
```

1. What is correct way to do user input parsing
2. How to do it with EF Core?

Comment: Why don't you just use `plainto_tsquery('simple','Apple street 1/3 13-74')`?

Comment: @jjanes plainto_tsquery looks like what i need, thanks! I'm new to pgsql and didn't know about it :)

Comment: @jjanes I found out another problem, I have to search by part of word, is there solution to use plainto_tsquery with searching by part of word. I know that there is prefix matching wildcard :* , can it be use with plainto_tsquery?